# How to list trust level of OpenPGP public keys in GnuPG?

Tags: gnupg, public-key, openpgp, trust

While I can determine the trust level I have placed on an individual OpenPGP public key by using the `--edit-key` command, is there a simple way to list all the public keys along with their trust levels from the command line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can export all configured owner trust through `gpg --export-ownertrust`.  The output is of the form

```
FINGERPRINT:TRUST:
```

For my own key (which has ultimate trust on my machine), there is following line included:

```
0D69E11F12BDBA077B3726AB4E1F799AA4FF2279:6:
```

It seems the trust level is corresponds to the number entered in the `trust` edit command plus one:

```
1 = I don't know or won't say (export: 2)
2 = I do NOT trust            (export: 3)
3 = I trust marginally        (export: 4)
4 = I trust fully             (export: 5)
5 = I trust ultimately        (export: 6)
```

The output of this command can also be imported again through `gpg --import-ownertrust`.

Comment: if I edit the key and select 1, it shows 2 instead. If I don't know is it considered as "I do NOT trust" ?

Comment: This is exactly what I described: the values of `gpg --edit-key`/`trust` does not have the same number when running `--export-ownertrust`, but maps to values larger by one. "I don't know" having value 1 in `--edit-key` will show up as `2` in the export. The output of this command is not meant to be user-readable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small script to do this more easily: [gpg-list-ownertrust.py](https://gist.github.com/F30/388ff62601eaa53e9f2ce247443e3ad4)

It is based on the [python-gnupg](https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/) library, which fortunately makes access to the ownertrust level very convenient.